# Vertex AI deploy custom model to an endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

After I run

```
gcloud beta ai endpoints deploy-model (ENDPOINT : --region=REGION) --display-name=DISPLAY_NAME --model=MODEL [--accelerator=[count=COUNT],[type=TYPE]] [--deployed-model-id=DEPLOYED_MODEL_ID] [--disable-container-logging] [--enable-access-logging] [--machine-type=MACHINE_TYPE] [--max-replica-count=MAX_REPLICA_COUNT] [--min-replica-count=MIN_REPLICA_COUNT] [--service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT] [--traffic-split=[DEPLOYED_MODEL_ID=VALUE,…]] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```

I got error "(gcloud.beta.ai.endpoints.deploy-model) INVALID_ARGUMENT: AUTOMATIC_RESOURCES is not one of the supported deployment resources types for Model projects/.../locations/us-central1/models/...

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

can you paste the exactly command you entered (obfuscating the sensitive information it may have [ie. project id, users, accounts, etc] with some string pattern [ie. xxxxxxxx or nnnnnnnn]?

it looks like a syntax error and the real command may help with that.